# JPA - Paginate a list of childs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, many-to-many

I'm currently developing an application with Spring as backend and have some troubles with JpaRepository.

We have a system with some Members that can be in some Organizations, so a member can be in multiple Organizations and an Organization can have multiples Members.

In my Member class I have :

```
@ManyToMany
private List<Organization> organizations;
```

And in the Organization class :

```
@ManyToMany
private List<Member> members;
```

Here is my problem:
I need to return a paginated list of the members of an organization, the problem is that I want to use JpaRepository to have a simplest implementation of the pagination system but I can't manage to retrieve the members that are in an Organization.

Here is something I tried in the member repository:

```
   Page<Member> findAllByOrganizationsContains(@Param("organization") Organization organization, Pageable pageable);
```

But this returns me nothing, the problem is that I don't understand how to get the members from an organization as this member can be in multiple organizations.

Any idea ?

Comment: Write your own Hql query using inner join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this way

```
@Entity
public class Organization{
     @Column(name = "organization_id")
     private long organizationId;

     @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     @JoinTable(name = "organization_members",
             joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id") },
             inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "member_id") })
     private List<Member> organizationMembers= new ArrayList<Member>();
}

@Entity
public class Member{
     @Column(name = "member_id")
     private long memberId;
}
```

In your repository

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM Organization o JOIN o.organizationMembers m where o.organizationId = ?1")
Page<Members> getAllMembersByOrganization(long organizationId , Pageable pageable);
```